# Who is the mother of Freyr and Freyja?

Tags: norse

Skadi seems to marry Njord after Freyja and Freyr are born. The only other figure I can find is Nerthus, though information on her seems scarce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different sources imply different things. In some, the mother seems to be [the unnamed sister of Njörðr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister-wife_of_Nj%C3%B6r%C3%B0r). In [the Ynglinga Saga](http://omacl.org/Heimskringla/ynglinga.html), Snorri Strurluson writes

> While Njord was with the Vanaland people he had taken his own sister in marriage, for that was allowed by their law; and their children were Frey and Freya. But among the Asaland people it was forbidden to intermarry with such near relations.

The same thing is implied in the [Lokasenna](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe10.htm), when Loki claims

> "Give heed now, Njorth, | nor boast too high,
> No longer I hold it hid;
> With thy sister hadst thou | so fair a son,
> Thus hadst thou no worse a hope."

However, the [Gylfaginning](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre04.htm) implies that the mother was indeed Skadi:

> Njördr has to wife the woman called Skadi, daughter of Thjazi the giant.
>
> . . .
>
> "Njördr in Nóatún begot afterward two children: the son was called Freyr, and the daughter Freyja; they were fair of face and mighty.

The claim that the mother is [Nerthus](http://norse-mythology.org/gods-and-creatures/the-vanir-gods-and-goddesses/nerthus/) seems to be mainly based on etymology, and not on any specific writings.

Answer (score 9):

There is another candidate for Njord's sister: [Njorun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nj%C3%B6run). Her claim isn't a lot better than Nerthus', based mainly on linguistic similiarity. Njorun turns up in a list of goddesses, and in kennings. (Dream-Njorun, for night, appears in [Alvissmal](http://www.northvegr.org/the%20eddas/the%20poetic%20edda%20%20-%20thorpe%20translation/alv%C3%ADssm%C3%A1l%20-%20the%20lay%20of%20the%20dwarf%20alvis.html).) You can read more about the [case for Njorun](https://www.academia.edu/2315070/Goddesses_Unknown_I_Nj%C7%ABrun_and_the_Sister-Wife_of_Nj%C7%ABr%C3%B0r), but the identity of Njord's sister/wife is clearly one of those mysteries that will never be resolved.